# Database upgrade issues with SSDT

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-data-tools, sql-update

I've been using SSDT for my database design for the past 9 months on a project and I'm about to abandon it for DbUp. Hopefully, there's a simpler solution...

Here's the problem. I have a database with the following table:

```
Persons
-----------
Id (PK)
Name
Email
```

I would like to upgrade my database to allow a person to have multiple email addresses:

```
Persons      EmailAddresses
-----------  ----------------
ID (PK)      ID (PK)
Name         PersonId (FK)
             Email
```

To do this all within SSDT without dataloss I would need to do some fancy Pre & Post deployment scripting:

```
-- PreDeployment.sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.Tables where [name] = 'Persons')
BEGIN

    CREATE Table TMP_Persons (ID, Name);
    CREATE Table TMP_EmailAddresses (ID, PersonId, Email);

    SELECT INTO TMP_Persons FROM Persons
    SELECT INTO TMP_EmailAddresses FROM Persons

    DELETE FROM Persons

END

-- PostDeployment.sql

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.Tables where [name] = 'TMP_Persons')
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO Persons FROM TMP_Persons
    SELECT INTO EmailAddresses FROM TMP_EmailAddresses
    DROP TABLE TMP_Persons;
    DROP TABLE TMP_EmailAddresses;
END
```

This (although tricky) is do-able and I've been doing this for majority of my changes. However, the problem comes where you have multiple versions of your database. For example, I have the following scenarios:

- New Developers - No prior database
- Dev Machine    - Database is very current
- Production     - Database is a week or more old

In the event that Production is more out-of-date than the dev machine (possibly from not deploying for a while or from needing to rollback) the above script may fail. This means that the Dev would need to know and take into account prior versions of the database.

For example, say that the Persons table was previously named Users. I would have to account for this possibility in my Pre-Deployment script.

```
-- PreDeployment.sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.Tables where [name] = 'Users')
BEGIN

    CREATE Table TMP_Persons (ID, Name);
    CREATE Table TMP_EmailAddresses (ID, PersonId, Email);

    SELECT INTO TMP_Persons FROM Users
    SELECT INTO TMP_EmailAddresses FROM Users

    DELETE FROM Persons

END

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.Tables where [name] = 'Persons')
BEGIN

    CREATE Table TMP_Persons (ID, Name);
    CREATE Table TMP_EmailAddresses (ID, PersonId, Email);

    SELECT INTO TMP_Persons FROM Persons
    SELECT INTO TMP_EmailAddresses FROM Persons

    DELETE FROM Persons

END
```

As time goes on and more variations occur the PreDeployment script is going to get very chaotic and error-prone. This just seems unmanageable to me. Aside from switching to DbUp or something else, is there a better way to do this within SSDT?

Comment: I don't see how you get away from having to manage stuff like this, but including the scripts instead of directly typing them helps somewhat (use :r .\scriptname.sql in the pre/post script). Also, I'd recommend removing the moving parts once you know production is up to date. Comment out the includes and they'll stop running each time. Better way would likely be to tie these sorts of changes to a version table - much easier to check than column/table names.

Comment: I think the reason why I'm seeing DbUp as a way to avoid this sort of problem is that DbUp is a more step-based approach & doesn't care what version the database is currently in.  For example, to do the above in DbUp I would just write scripts that assume the previous were run for example, "Script01 - Initial Create User", "Script02 - Rename User to Person", "Script03 - Allow Multiple Emails". When writing Script03 I don't have to be concerned with what version the database is because I can assume that Script01 and Script02 have already successfully run. This simplifies the script quite a bit.

Comment: @PeterSchott - Re: "Better way would likely be to tie these sorts of changes to a version table - much easier to check than column/table names." At that point, you're pretty much just creating DbUp functionality in your SSDT script. Might as well just use DbUp...

Comment: Except I'm not creating DbUp functionality except for the migration pieces. Most of the time I find myself using the "refactor" functionality inside SSDT to make changes and I rarely have to do these sorts of operations in any of the DBs I maintain. Yes, refactor ops come up from time to time, but they're pretty rare. The ability to just say "make this database look like this" without worrying about how we got there is a huge plus in many cases. This is only amplified if you ever have a "partial" release where some pieces need to go but not others.

Comment: @PeterSchott - You make a good point. I wasn't intending to make this a SSDT vs DbUp question & there's definitely a lot of merit to using SSDT to simplify creation from a "make it look like this" perspective. That's actually the main reason I started the project with SSDT. However, in my case I have **a lot** of refactor ops that get deployed to our databases at random (or more specifically _unknown_) times, which might make DbUp more favorable if there isn't an easy way to do it in SSDT.

Comment: Probably not in this case, though it's probably worth some conversations with the dev team there about a little more forward planning to try to get some idea of where the software is heading to avoid so many refactor operations. :)  If I were using SSDT to handle this, I'd really look at DB version numbers and using files for the pre/post deploy scripts. Check version, run script if appropriate for that version. Besides, I find that you can't always rely on all scripts having been run. Miss one and you could have issues.

Comment: @jaytre Just curious... What did you end up using?

Comment: I'm using DbUp & so far am glad the switch has worked well for me